# Visual Studio 2017 keeps re-formatting my code and it's driving me nuts

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

There is 1 page, and only 1 page in all the pages I've ever built that has this problem.  Whenever I save my "Settings.aspx" page in Visual Studio, it loves to play a funny prank and re-format all my code!  And no, there's no other developer here playing an actual prank on me.  I thought this particular issue pops up because I have an unclosed tag somewhere, but I ran my code through a unclosed tag checker, and it says I'm good.

Haven't really tried any fix, since I have no idea where to begin.  I don't want to turn off Visual Studio's IntelliSense and the auto-formatting that happens as I type.  But I certainly want to turn off the auto-formatting that happens EVERY SINGLE TIME I press the Save button.  Which I do a lot..."Computers 101" right?

My beautiful code changes from this:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3>Job Titles</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            <h3>Job Change Reasons</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            <h3>Employment Types</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

To this:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3>Job Titles</h3></td><td>
            &nbsp; </td><td>
            <h3>Job Change Reasons</h3></td><td>
            &nbsp; </td><td>
            <h3>Employment Types</h3></td></tr><tr></table>
```

And it's driving me nuts!  It not only reformats it, but somehow it wipes out an element and then I get an error in my code.

Please help save my sanity..

***UPDATE***

Well I did see 1 option that I wanted to change to make things more useful.  But nothing that applies to this particular issue.  My VS seems to have a mind of it's own.  I adjusted the specific formatting setting for "td" so it would auto-format like this:

```
<td>
    &nbsp;
</td>
```

And yet when it does it's crazy re-formatting, it ***still*** adjusts my stuff like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        &nbsp; </td><td>
        &nbsp; </td></tr><tr>
```

This code is smack dab in the middle of the body, so I don't think the Javascript options apply.  Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn this off for HTML in particular by going to 'Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML (Web Forms) -> Formatting'. There are a few options there that you can play with to get you what you're looking for.

Here's another link for reading on the topic: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21139